# Control smartphone camera from PC

Tags: tcp, peripherals, smartphone

Can a smartphone camera be used and controlled from a PC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of apps that work just like this. Some of these are free others are paid. I suggest Droidcam because I have used it myself sometimes and I really like it. It also has a great guide page.

- Droidcam https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/connect/
- IP webcam
- Epoccam
- Smartcam

Comment: Alright, thx. And to be more specific, what are the communication protocols that allow this? I mean, on what technical tools are these apps based on? (More than just "wifi" or "networks")